# Activating input:valid in outer div

Tags: css

I want the input:valid effect to trigger at the outer div just as the
focus-within does. Is there any way?

```css
.inputBox {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  transition: .3s;
}

input {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.inputBox:focus-within,
input:valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox">
  <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="E-mail" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (which is yet to be implemented in browsers):

> The `:has()` CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the selectors passed as parameters (relative to the `:scope` of the given element) match at least one element.

```css
.inputBox:has(> input:valid)
```

I know this is unhelpful to you now, but might be to others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use input without period in front of it. Because input is a tag and not the class unlike .inputBox

```
.inputBox {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    transition: .3s;
}

input {
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.inputBox:focus-within,
 input:valid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```